# split string by order like 3x2x1

Tags: php

(PHP) how can I split a string in multiple strings separated by comma,

like is I have a string `"Hello my neighbor"`,

then after the split process, it should be

`("Hello my neighbor","Hello my","Hello neighbor","my neighbor","Hello","my","neighbor")`

Comment: I would make a function that takes max length of combo array as an argument, 3 in your case and the input string. Then use explode() on the string to make an array of substrings separated by spaces (or another delimiter) Then run a recursive function inside that, which implode() a new string starting with a different element each time, adds a new element and runs a check, weather this combination already exists. All this probably inside some for loop with $i < count($exploded_string_arr) A fun task, but i will leave the implementation to you :)

Comment: the thing that you need is to get all possible permutations of words in the sentence. Check this article http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```html
<?php
$string = "Hello my neighbor";
$str = explode(" ",$string);
$newArray = [];
$newArray[] = $string;
for($i = 0; $i<count($str); $i++) {
 if($i <= 1) { 
  $newArray[] = $str[$i]." ".$str[$i+1];
  if($i != 0) {
   $newArray[] = $str[$i-1]." ".$str[$i+1];
  }
 }
 $newArray[] = $str[$i];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks sir , i think it will repeat some of strings